# Array of String to Date, Jsp-Servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets

I got stuck while converting Array of String to Array of Date

```
{
  String[] departureDate=request.getParameterValues("departureDate"); 
}
```

How do I convert the above **Strings** to **Date[]** ?

Comment: First of all, you need to know what format the date is in. Second you need to parse it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java string to date conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion)

Comment: I have sent dates in array of String  from the JSP page. Now in servlet I want to convert that string array to date array. So how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem.

```
 String[] departureDate=request.getParameterValues("departureDate");

    List<Date> date=(List<Date>) new Date();
    for(String dateToConvert : departureDate) {
        try {
            Date convertedDate=  formatter.parse(dateToConvert);
            date.add(convertedDate);
        }
        catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all the sentence:

```
request.getParameterValues("departureDate");
```

belongs to ServletRequest.

when you use that code you will get an array of String from your input with name departureDate so if you had something like this for example:

```
    <input type="checkbox" name="departureDate" value="26">day
    <input type="checkbox" name="departureDate" value="04">month
    <input type="checkbox" name="departureDate" value="1988">year
```

You will get the array with the values 26,04,1988.

as you can see that is a date, right?

Now everyone want to know what values do you have? so we can help you because you cannot transform a String[] to a Date[].

Comment: Yes that is a Servlet Request but in my JSP form I am taking multiple dates "2017/01/22","2015/11/23","1996/12/02" using the same name departureDate. Hence while passing from Jsp to Servlet it goes as a array of Strings so I need to convert that array to Array of Dates